# Cannot sink Windowed queried streaming data to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

Using Spark Structured Streaming I am trying to sink streaming data to a MongoDB collection. The issue is that I am querying my data using a **window** as following:

```
def basicAverage(df): 
  return df.groupby(window(col('timestamp'), "1 hour", "5 minutes"), col('stationcode')) \
  .agg(avg('mechanical').alias('avg_mechanical'), avg('ebike').alias('avg_ebike'),  avg('numdocksavailable').alias('avg_numdocksavailable'))
```

And it seems that mongodb integration cannot support a writeStream containing windowed data because when I run the script, my collection remains empty and no error shows up. I tried to delete the window option on my query and the sink worked like a charm.

Here is my sink method:

```
queryBasicAvg.writeStream.format('mongodb').queryName("basicAvg") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "./tmp/pyspark7/").option("forceDeleteTempCheckpointLocation", "true") \
  .option('spark.mongodb.connection.uri', 'mongodb://127.0.0.1') \
  .option("spark.mongodb.database", 'velibprj').option("spark.mongodb.collection", 'stationsBasicAvg') \
  .outputMode("append").start()
```

Any thought on how to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using foreach() sink method.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).